# Is Myriad Pro finally available for use as a web font? (It's now used by Apple as a web font)

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

Apple is using "Myriad Pro Set" as a web font. I'm assuming that somehow we can now purchase a license to use Myriad Pro as a web font.

Adobe [says](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFont&code=MYRP10003000) the font is available for web use. But, the only info they provide is a link to Typekit (owned by Adobe), which does offer "Myriad Pro" but Typekit's Myriad Pro is a serif font -- not the sans-serif that Apple has popularized.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 11):

For a subscription fee at Adobe Fonts, the [web font](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/myriad) is available.

As for the fonts being different (serif vs. sans-serif), here is a side-by-side comparison of the font off apple.com (left) and the font off the Adobe page you linked to (right):

[image]

As you can see, there is no difference between the two, at least with this "G" character, and I couldn't find any other noticeable differences.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a free and pretty close font, you can use PT Sans
[https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT%20Sans)

Comment: But PT Sans looks nothing like Myriad Pro :(